# Уникален ли FK (Внешний ключ) по умолчанию?

Tags: sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста уникален ли FK по умолчанию?

Comment: Если бы FK был уникален, то создать связи многие к одному и многие ко многим было бы невозможно

Comment: FK вообще не имеет физического воплощения - это правило!